# Google Maps API - use "search nearby" feature?

Tags: javascript, search, google-maps, geolocation

I have a function that geo-tags items using Google Maps API based on basic address information like City, State, Country, etc.

However - it would be REALLY Useful to give a reference point so that Google will first look for the address near a point that I define- similar to a "Locate XYZ Street, San Francisco, CA, near 78.34561, -24.56678". (Note: these aren't real Lat/Long values...)

I.E. - this would help increase the Geo-Tag map precision for items with partial Address information.

IS THIS POSSIBLE with Google Maps API ver.2?

It seems possible in Google Maps - the "Search Nearby" function.

I can paste code here, but it's long.

THANK YOU! I'm really stuck finding out about this, but it seems like an interesting possibility...

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Viewport biasing](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/index.html#Viewports) in v2, or upgrade to v3 and use [that version](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Viewports). v2 is deprecated, and in v3 you don't need an api key - it's a good transition to do. :-)